# Работа с формами в Visual C++ 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

Как в студии текст из textbox1 при нажатии на buton1 перевести в label1, так чтобы он затерся в textbox1?

Правильно ли я делаю?

Двойной клик на button1:

```
this->label1->text=textbox1.text;
this->textBox1->text="";
```

Comment: Вы почему-то пишете на C++/CLI (это **не** C++). Бросайте это дело, переходите на C#.

Comment: Мне так рассказывали, а писать сказали на плюсах

Comment: а код я так понимаю вообще не правильный? могли бы вы его подкоректировать?

Comment: ладно с этим вопросом я разобался. А если мне надо выполнить дополнение задания, к примеру: ввел текст в текстбокс, нажал первій батон, он вписал текст в лейбл и затер его в текст бокс.

Comment: пусть мне надо при нажатии на вторую кнопку, чтобі он заменялся текстом два. Например если введен текст "1", нажимая на батон2 он заменяеться текстом"2" єто какое собітие textchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующие предложения

```
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void okButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 if ( !System::String::IsNullOrWhiteSpace( this->textBox->Text ) )
                 {
                     this->helloLabel->Text = this->textBox->Text; 
                     this->textBox->Clear();
                 }
             }
```

Только замените `helloLabel` и `textBox` на имена своих идентификаторов.

Comment: спасибо я сделал немного иначе:

Comment: private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender,           System::EventArgs^  e)      {
                   label1->Text="";
         }
     private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender,      System::EventArgs^  e) {
    label1->Text=textBox1->Text;
    textBox1->Text="";
   }

Comment: а если форма должна закриться при  нажатии на button3 ?private:       System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender,           System::EventArgs^  e) {
        MessageBox->Show("This program will     close");
                  Form1->Close();
   } оно не работает

Comment: @Muscled Boy  Если данный вопрос решен, то лучше закрыть его (то есть выбрать подходящий ответ) и задать новый вопрос. .